# Remove matching lines from yaml file

Tags: sed, yaml

I have a yaml file:

```
version: xxx
description: xxx
inspec_version: "~> 4"
depends:
- name: yyy
  url: random-url
supports:
- platform: aws
```

How can I remove this from the file?

```
depends:
- name: yyy
  url: random-url
```

so the file will look like:

```
version: xxx
description: xxx
inspec_version: "~> 4"
supports:
- platform: aws
```

The name and url value can be random but it will always be `depends: name, url`.

I tried this with sed for the first line but it didn't work:

```
 sed -i '^depends:' test.yml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this (I've removed the `-i`, and you can add it back when you're happy with the result):

```bash
sed '/^depends:/{N;N;d}' test.yml
```

Details:

- `/^depends:/` matches the first of the three lines
- `{…}` goups the commands to be executed when the above pattern matched
- `;` separates successive commands
- `N` appends the following line to the current pattern space (the line you were editing when the match occurred); this happens twice, resulting in the pattern space holding the line matching the pattern, plus the two following lines
- `d` deletes the pattern space

Answer (score 2):

With a tool that understand YAML, such as [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```bash
yq 'del(.depends)' infile.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with `sed -i '/^depends:/d' test.yml`.

Comment: thanks, any idea how I can remove the 3 lines when that matches?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed '/^depends:/,/url:/d' your_file
```

It deletes all lines appearing and between lines that match the two patterns
`^depends:` and `url:`

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` to do the
substitution in-place:

```
sed -i '/^depends:/,/url:/d' your_file
```